USB Wireless Headphones not working
I have a Turtle Beach Ear Force Stealth 600 Gen 2 USB wireless headphones that do not work when plugged into my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 23.10.
Output of lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. Logi Bolt Receiver 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 10f5:0043 Turtle Beach Xbox Controller 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 

Update: I installed xboxdrv and it still does not work. Why did I try those drivers? Because the headset identifies as "Xbox Controller" on Windows.

We need to know more about your problem. But...The first thing is to check if your receiver (from what I understand in this model the connection takes place with a mini USB receiver) is being recognized by your system.
You can use thelsusb command to see if your device appers in the system.
A quick search showed me that several users have had problems using this equipment on Linux (not necessarily on a Raspberry PI).
Could you describe better what your problem exactly is?

I tried LSUSB and the output was the following:
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. Logi Bolt Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 10f5:0043 Turtle Beach Xbox Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

